# Python Matplotlib and MySQL and Ginput

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib

I'm looking into using Python with MySQLdb and Matplotlib. I'm looking to use the values of a query within a matplotlib scatter plot based on a ginput plot. I have the following working:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import random
import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys
from collections import defaultdict


##### Start the query ####
db = mdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'xbee')
start = raw_input("Enter Start Date: ")

part_1 = "SELECT XBEE_ADDRESS_AL, XBEE_TEMPERATURE FROM xbeereadings WHERE Date='"
part_2 = start
part_3 = "'"
query_1 = part_1 + part_2 + part_3
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute(query_1)

s = cur.fetchall()
print s
d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)

i = 0
temp = [item[i] for item in d.values()]

figure(figsize=(15, 8))
img = mpimg.imread('floor.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, cmap=cm.hot)
print "Left click to plot the sensors point on the image - Middle Click to remove the last point - Right click to End plotting"

# pts would be used with ginput to collect the place the sensor would be located. It returns the example array below
pts = ginput(n=0, timeout=0, mouse_add=1, mouse_pop=2, mouse_stop=3)

x = map(lambda x: x[0],pts) # Extract the values from pts
y = map(lambda x: x[1],pts) 
t = temp

result = zip(x,y,t)

img = mpimg.imread('floor.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, cmap=cm.hot, vmin=-20, vmax=40)
scatter(x, y, marker='h', c=t, s=150, vmin=-20, vmax=40) #add colour c=?
print t

# Add cmap
colorbar()
show()
```

EDIT: I got the previous part of the question working (how to use a query values as a cmap value) as shown in the new code. I have taken the temperature (divided by 100 to get a valid number) and then placed it in the plot.

The questions I would now like some help/code/starting points for are:

1 - How can I assign a ginput point to a sensor Id from the query? There will be 3 sensors that are placed on the plot and so I would like to assign the id and temperature to a single point.
The problem I have is that it assigned the first value of t to the first point - and the second value of t to the second point. How can I set which temperature value is assigned to a specific point?

If I do fetch all for say 1 hour it's going to give multiple values for the same sensor. I would like some kind of time control where I can plot the first set of results for each sensor - and then press a button and the next result for each sensor is plotted. They will all be running at the same time so there will always be a value to plot for each sensor id.

Also It's giving this error -

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py:808: RuntimeWarning: invali
d value encountered in divide
  z = np.take(y, i0) + (xn-np.take(b,i0))*dy/db
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heatmap2.py", line 51, in <module>
    show()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 143, in show
    _show(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 108, in
 __call__
    self.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", lin
e 69, in mainloop
    Tk.mainloop()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 325, in mainloop
    _default_root.tk.mainloop(n)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Is that because both values are the same and so the cmap only has 1 value? It goes away if I set one of the temperatures in the query to say 0.56.

I hope that makes sense

Comment: Can you replace the data sourcing sections of your code with fake (random works fine) data?  It makes testing/figuring out what is wrong with your code a lot easier, which means you are more likely to get people to look at your problem.

Comment: @tcaswell - Sorry it wasn't the clearest question was it. I have updated the code with the examples returned from the query and pts - does that make it clearer?
As you can see there are 2 sensors returned from the query - 1 and 2 (the 3rd value in). I need to link that first sensor to one of the values in points - and the second sensor to the second value in points. 
I then need to colour the plot points using the 4th value from the query based on a cmap...
Later I am looking to replot using the second temperature based on the plot - but that's for some other time

Comment: Does the SQL stuff actually relate to your problem?  It looks like you can get data out of it just fine.  Unless I am missing something, and tho SQL in _essential_ to this problem, you can delete those bits (but leave the results) altogether.

Comment: @tcaswell - I guess now you mention it I have solved the data part so yeah I have remove that. I have expanded the rows section to show what a full result may look like and to make it a little clearer. So I need to plot the first 2 temperatures for each sensor (in this case plot the first results of sensor 1 and 2). Following that I need to be able to re-plot this time using the second set of results but using the same ginput values...

Comment: I am a bit confused about what the problem(s) are.  If you have more than on problem (that can be cleanly sepreated) it is better to do one question per-problem than fold them all in to a single question.  This makes them easier to answer and makes them more useful for future users.

Comment: @tcaswell - I think it would be single question. In the code above there are 2 points returned from ginput (pts). After I fetch the query data from mysql I get the results - "rows". As you can see there are multiple values(temperatures) for the same sensor (there is sensor 1 and sensor 2 which provide data every 10 seconds). I want to be able to plot a single temperature for each sensor. Then using a control (a button perhaps) be able to replot - this time using the second value for each sensor - but without having to go through and specify the ginput values again. Is that any clearer?

Answer (score 2):

You are running into a peculiarity of `ScalarMappables`.  They take care of normalizing the data to be in the range [0, 1] and passing that value to the color map.  By default it sets the bottom of the range to `min(values_you_are_mapping)` and the top to the max, which if all your values are identical results in the width of the range being zero, and the mapping `(v - max_v) / (max_v - min_v)` blows up.  The solution is to tell it what the range should be by

```
imshow(..., vmin=min_t, vmax=max_t)
scatter(..., vmin=min_t, vmax=max_t)
```

where `max_t` and `min_t` are the maximum and minimum temperatures you could ever get.  This will also make the color mapping consistent across all of your figures.

Comment: I added the values and it's removed the error. Presumably I still need to keep the calculation to give a value between 0 and 1? It is working so I'm presuming yes...
Thanks for the help so far - really appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to do the normalization your self, but if you do, it will happily re-normalize your normalized data.

Comment: Hi, I'm just revisiting this one. I added the vmin and max but it's still complaining the values aren't between 0-1. I tried it on code in a previous example and it worked perfectly...but the code above doesn't seem to like it. Error = "Invalid rgb arg "23.44" gray (string) must be in range 0-1"...any ideas or should I make another question?

Comment: @Ollie create a new question with the _minimal_ amount of code you need to reproduce the error