# Matplotlib cmap values must be between 0-1

Tags: matplotlib

I am having trouble with the code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from pylab import *
import sys


s = (('408b2e00', '24.21'), ('408b2e0c', '22.51'), ('4089e04a', '23.44'), ('4089e04d', '24.10'))

temp = [x[1] for x in s]
print temp

figure(figsize=(15, 8))

pts = [(886.38864047695108, 349.78744809964849), (1271.1506973277974, 187.65500904929195), (1237.272277227723, 860.38363675077176), (910.58751197700428, 816.82566805067597)]

x = map(lambda x: x[0],pts) # Extract the values from pts
y = map(lambda x: x[1],pts) 
t = temp

result = zip(x,y,t)

img = mpimg.imread('floor.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, cmap=cm.hot)
scatter(x, y, marker='h', c=t, s=150, vmin=-20, vmax=40)
print t

# Add cmap
colorbar()
show()
```

Given the temperature in s - I am trying to set the values of the cmap so I can use temperatures between -10 and 30 instead of having to used values between 1 and 0. I have set the vmin and vmax values but it still gives me the error below:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "23.44" to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "23.44" gray (string) must be in range 0-1
```

I have use earlier code to simplify the problem and have been successful. This example below works and shows what I am trying to (hopefully) do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

figure(figsize=(15, 8))
# use ginput to select markers for the sensors
matplotlib.pyplot.hot()

markers = [(269, 792, -5), (1661, 800, 20), (1017, 457, 30)]
x,y,t = zip(*markers)

img = mpimg.imread('floor.png')
imgplot = plt.imshow(img, cmap=cm.hot)
scatter(x, y, marker='h', c=t, s=150, vmin=-10, vmax=30)

colorbar()
show()
```

Any ideas why only the second solution works? I am working with dynamic values i.e inputs from mysql and user selected points and so the first solution would be much easier to get working later on (the rest of that code is in this question: [Full program code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888693/python-matplotlib-and-mysql-and-ginput) )

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are handing in strings instead of floats, change this line:

```
temp = [float(x[1]) for x in s]
```

`matplotlib` tries to be good about guessing what you mean and lets you define gray as a string of a float between [0, 1] which is what it is trying to do with your string values (and complaining because it is not in than range).